# problem - multiple index in latex

Tags: macros

I find here an example and use it for my multiple index. This code in Latex works, but I want to use the newcommand `\smindexxspecial[\ITerm]{beccari}` instead `\index[\ITerm]{beccari}` or `\smsindexspecial{IServ{www.wikipedia.org}` instead `\index[\IServ]{www.wikipedia.org}`. For this I do this one `\newcommand{\smindexxspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge#2} \index[1]{#2}}`. But it doesn't work.

Does anybody have an Idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newcommand{\ITerm}{IndexTerms}
\newcommand{\IServ}{IndexServs}

\newcommand{\MyLarge}{\Large}

\newcommand{\smindexxspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge#2} \index{#2}}
\newcommand{\smindexspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge#2}\index{#2}}
\newcommand{\smindexvspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge#2}\index{#2}}
\newcommand{\smsindexspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge\url{#2}}\index{#2}}

\makeindex[name= \ITerm, Concept Index,columns=3]
\makeindex[name= \IServ,title= Websites,columns=3]

\begin{document}

Here is a list of things and people
\begin{itemize}
 \item \LaTeX \index[\IServ]{www.wikipedia.org}  %\smsindexspecial{IServ{www.wikipedia.org}
 \item Beccari \index[\ITerm]{beccari}           %\smindexxspecial[\ITerm]{beccari}
 \item Gregorio \index[\ITerm]{gregorio}
\end{itemize}

And this is the end of the story.

\printindex[\IServ]

\indexprologue{\small In this index you’ll find only
famous people’s names}
\printindex[\ITerm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for including me among the "famous people's names". `;-)` Just use `\index[#1]{#2}` in the definitions and call `\smindexxspecial{\ITerm}{beccari}`

Comment: Thank for your clue. But it works as comment. I see it on my pdf. But my problem is an other one. ;)

Comment: ok I try it now.

Comment: Thank you egreg. I used before \index[#1]{#2} too, but it didn't work. I notice that I used smindexxspecial wrong. ;)

Comment: @egreg It's weird on the Windows Computer work this one

\newcommand{\smsindexspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge\url{#2}}\index[#1]{#2}}, \item wiki \smsindexspecial{\IServ}{www.wikipedia.org} But on my macbook it doesn't work, textmaker gives an error like undefined control sequence.